# How to implement a REST API with akka typed actor system

Tags: scala, api, rest, http, akka

Im trying to start a REST API using scala with akka-http. Im new with akka and actor model paradigm so i want to implement a typed actor system but im getting this sbt compiling error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem (implicit ActorRefFactory required: if outside of an Actor you need an implicit ActorSystem, inside of an actor this should be the implicit ActorContext)
[error]     val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
```

Any idea what is going on here?, this is my code based on an example from the akka documentation:

```
object FeedAggregatorServer {
  def apply(): Behavior[Nothing] =
    Behaviors.setup[Nothing](context => new FeedAggregatorServer(context))
}

class FeedAggregatorServer(context: ActorContext[Nothing]) extends AbstractBehavior[Nothing](context) {
  context.log.info("Application started")

  override def onMessage(msg: Nothing): Behavior[Nothing] = {
    // No need to handle any messages
    Behaviors.unhandled
  }

  override def onSignal: PartialFunction[Signal, Behavior[Nothing]] = {
    case PostStop =>
      context.log.info("Application stopped")
      this
  }

}

object FeedAggregatorApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ActorSystem[Nothing](FeedAggregatorServer(), "FeedAggregatorServer")

    val route =
      concat (
        path("") {
          complete("Hello, World!")
        },
        path("feed") {
          complete("Hello!")
        }
      )

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }

}
```

Routing should be in FeedAggregatorServer maybe or ...?

Comment: Akka Http uses classic actorsystem, and you might need to convert typed system to classic system.
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an `implicit` `akka.actor.ActorSystem` (note, a classic actor system is required, though this will change in future versions of akka-http) when creating your akka-http server.  You can learn more about [interoperation between classic and typed actor systems in the akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html) (as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4268228/shankar-shastri).

Based on your code you'll want to implicitly provide the classic actor system like so:

```scala
// you could move this to your other imports
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter._

val typedSystem = ActorSystem[Nothing](FeedAggregatorServer(), "FeedAggregatorServer")
implicit val classicSystem = typedSystem.toClassic
...
```